# Multiple transformations within a single projection on epsg.io

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I am referring to https://epsg.io/24313

Here, EPSG:24313 is written in bold at the top of the page, and then there are multiple subprojections listed underneath. I am confused about which one to use, and indeed, about what they mean by "code".

Currently, I'm using the 24313 as follows:

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,24313),eps := 50, minPoints := 100)
```

Here is the image from the same link pasted above:

[image]

Comment: those are possible transformations to lat/lon (4326) - your software should pick the correct one for you

Comment: I suggest editing the title of the question because it is misleading now.

Comment: thanks, but since 24313 has unit of meters, can't I just stick to 24313 in the DBSCAN as I have written in the question (if I want distance in meters?)

Comment: Furthermore, the transformations section says "to EPSG 4326", and then shows multiple codes below! Can anyone please elaborate on this?

Comment: By reading your question I do not quite understand where you are asking anything about distances, but if you stick with EPSG:24313 you do not need to worry about transformations.

Comment: I am using distance based transformation here (show in question as well): ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,24313),eps := 50, minPoints := 100)

Comment: For EPSG 24313, it says: "Pakistan - onshore. , accuracy 999.0 m, code 1247 (default)". Does this mean the accuracy is +/- 999 meters?

Comment: It actually means that the accuracy in unknown https://epsg.org/transformation_1247/Kalianpur-1962-to-WGS-84-1.html? `Care! DMA ellipsoid is inconsistent with EPSG ellipsoid - transformation parameter values may not be appropriate. No accuracy estimate available.` But that affects the conversion into WGS84. The distances between the mapped objects are not so random so you can still cluster by 50 m tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

What you see are not sub-projections but as the sub-title says, transformations. That means, methods to make a transformation from CRS EPSG:24313 into other coordinate systems.

By the way the official resource is epsg.org https://epsg.org/crs_24313/Kalianpur-1962-UTM-zone-43N.html?
not epsg.io, even epsg.io is more user friendly and the data on the site is derived from opsg.org.

One of the transformations that epsg.io lists is this one https://epsg.org/transformation_9234/Kalianpur-1962-to-WGS-84-5.html? So, it is a **transformation** with code **EPSG:9234**. There are other transformations for the coordinate reference system EPSG:24313. Each of them has an EPSG code in a category "transformations" and you can find more information about them from the the epsg.org site.

Comment: thanks, but since 24313 has unit of meters, can't I just stick to 24313 in the DBSCAN as I have written in the question (if I want distance in meters?)

Comment: Furthermore, the transformations section says "to EPSG 4326", and then shows multiple codes below! Can anyone please elaborate on this?

Comment: If you read the details many of the transformations have been developed for a smaller area than the one covered by EPSG:24313 and the accuracy of the transformation outside the studied area is uncertain.